# Read this puzzle!

Tags: cipher

> 983, 025, 169, 653, 419, 093, 440, 784, 752, 283, 514, 851, 547, 993

What is spelled?

Hint 1:

> Each number is a letter and commas are not important.

Hint 2:

> The title may help.

Hint 3:

> It is one word.

Hint 4:

> My best friend's name is Dewey.

Comment: Why have you already added three hints after 10 minutes?

Comment: Should I delete two of them and only add them after an hour or two?

Comment: In all honesty, all three hints were already pretty obvious.  In future just let your puzzle sit until it's obvious no one has any idea and everyone needs a hint.  Don't forget that people all around the world are up at different times.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the tip. This is my first question so I appreciate any tips on asking!

Comment: Given the hints, is the word 42 letters long?

Comment: Joe, I was assuming 14.

Comment: what does 0 stands for? space?

Comment: My assumption is that each 3 digit number equates to a single letter

Comment: @weejammaz That is correct, each 3 digit number equates to a single letter.

Comment: Would you all like another hint?

Comment: No repeat numbers means no repeat letters? Or no?

Comment: Letters do repeat, the numbers don't.

Comment: Here is my next hint: I have a good friend named Dewey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote

> CLASSIFICATION

using

> Dewey decimal system, and taking first letter of each category

Comment: Congratulations! That is correct! I hope that last hint wasn't too much of a giveaway.

Answer (score 5):

I think the word is

> CLASSIFICATION

because the numbers

> are are Dewey Decimal classes and the initial letters of these spell your word
>
>  
> 983 Chile,   025 Library operations,   169 Analogy,   653 Shorthand,   419 Sign languages,   093 Incunabula,   440 French & related Romance languages,   784 Instruments & Instrumental ensembles & their music,   752 Color,   283 Anglican churches,   514 Topology,   851 Italian poetry,   547 Organic chemistry,   993 New Zealand

Comment: Very Well Explained..

Comment: I would have accepted your answer, but shree.pat18 answered first.

Comment: @Wowsk - you are right to do so, and I learned interesting things about Dewey - nice puzzle!

Comment: Thanks! I was worried it was going to be too hard, and then worried that the last hint would give it away.

Comment: I know what you mean - it can be tough! - I look forward to your next puzzle someday - you could keep it hard for a few days as there are many really good solvers on this SE!

Comment: Meta PSE would be good for everyone to look at sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> Classification

Because

> If you take the first letter of the Dewey decimal system classifications corresponding to the numbers in the question, that's what it spells

More Info

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey_Decimal_Classification